# What might prevent a channel from retaining submitted content?

Tags: channel

I've just created a new channel; after populating it with content, I went to view it in the front end to find the channel:entries tag outputting zero content. On checking the channel's entries in the back end I discovered that none of the data I'd entered had been retained. I've tried re-entering data several times but it's never retained.

There's nothing weird about this channel; it consists of a single Grid field that is basically a near-exact copy of a Grid used in another channel -- which works fine. (The only difference, other than a different field name, is the removal of one column).

I've looked through the channel preferences (which, in any case, I created by duplicating the other Grid channel's prefs at the time I created the problematic channel) but can't see anything that might prevent a channel from storing data.

Can anyone suggest anything that might be causing this refusal to retain data?

[Additional info: when I originally created the channel I set it to make use of the 'Single Entries' add-on. I've removed it from that add-on so that it's now a 'normal' channel again, but it makes no difference; data is still not retained].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The problem arose from the fact that when I created the channel (channel B) I opted to duplicate the preferences of a channel (channel A) that had its 'Title' and 'URL Title' fields hidden via Publishing Layouts and the 'Hidden Tab' add-on. Channel A was set as a 'Single Entry' channel via that particular add-on, so its title and URL title were no longer needed in the editing page and could safely be hidden, reducing clutter).

By choosing to use the preferences of Channel A in creating Channel B, I also gave it the same Publishing Layout. So I was entering data into the channel but not giving it a Title or a URL Title (because those fields were hidden, out of sight and out of mind).

Temporarily making those fields visible again meant that I could populate them with data and thus have the entry retained. Having done so I could once again make the channel a 'Single Entry' type and safely re-hide the fields, since all further changes to that channel would be edits, not publishing new entries.

Anyway, I thought I'd post the cause and the solution here in case anyone else runs into the same problem, which is really just a consequence of duplicating the preferences of a visually-decluttered channel. Logical, but not necessarily immediately-obvious.